# regexp not cutting url proprerly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which is giving me a few headaches as all seems to work fine on paper, but when I put it in practice it gives me weird results.

The purpose of the code is to get in the variable "domainurlcut" the URL of the page and cut it, then it does a check to see if the url contains the prefix "www." If it does, it removes it.
All is working fine if I use the regexp:

```
domainurlcut = /\w+\.\w+/g.exec(domainurlcut);
```

But the issue with this is that it doesn't work if the url is www.google.co.uk. It will just cut it to google.co
Works fine instead with www.google.com as it will return google.com

I tried to address the issue by modifying that regexp into the following one (currently commented in the below code).

```
domainurlcut = /\w+\.\w+.\w+/g.exec(domainurlcut);
```

This addresses the issue of www.google.co.uk but then I have another issue.
If i test this with the domain www.thingiverse.com for example, the output of the alert is expected to be

```
"thingiverse.com"
```

but instead is:

```
   "thingiverse.com,thingiverse"
```

Can you help me out to understand what's wrong?
By checking the regexp on http://regexr.com/ it "should" work fine.

Full code below:

```
var domainurlcut = /(\w*\.+)+\w*/g.exec(window.location.href);

    if (/(www.)/g.test(domainurlcut)){  
        domainurlcut = /\.\w*.\w*.\w+/g.exec(domainurlcut); 
    //  domainurlcut = /\w+\.\w+.\w+/g.exec(domainurlcut);  
        domainurlcut = /\w+\.\w+/g.exec(domainurlcut);  
    }
    domainurlcut = domainurlcut[0];

    alert(domainurlcut);
```

Comment: Why you want to do it with regexp? And why you want to remove `www`? JFYI, some sites doesn't work without `www`

Comment: I would rather play with `location.host` property, if it starts with `www.` then trim it and you're done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var url;
url = 'www.thingiverse.com'
url = 'www.google.co.uk'
var domainurlcut = /(\w*.)([\w.-\/]*)/.exec(url);

console.log(domainurlcut);
var result = domainurlcut[2];

alert(result);
```

Comment: Hi @jtrs that almost works. I added it to my code and I managed to have it output .google.co.uk and .thingiverse.com i now need to remove the dot in front of the domain names

Comment: Managed to fix it integrating with the existing code. Amazing help, thank you!