# Remove "www." from domain name string

Tags: php, regex

How do I remove "www." from the url if it comes in the beginning only.

```
www.google.com --> google.com
```

I have tried the following so far, but this removes the "www." if it is in any place :

```
str_ireplace('www.','',$parsed_url);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you guys downvoted this quick !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regexp not cutting url proprerly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289369/regexp-not-cutting-url-proprerly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = "www.google.com";
echo preg_replace ("~^www\.~", "", $a);
```